# jquery flot mark a goal value and display its value

Tags: javascript, jquery, label, flot, axis

I am using jquery flot plugin to plot the graph.I just want to mark the goal value by plotting horizontal line and display its value.
I used markings to draw the line, but i don't know how to display its value. Give me some suggestions.

```
   var markings = [
    { yaxis: { from: 20, to: 20 }, color: "#E8E8E8" }
    ];
    var plot = $.plot("#" + divId, dataList, {
     grid : {
        hoverable : true,
        lineWidth : 1,
        markings : markings
    },
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a potential solution that appends a `div` to the plot. Replace `XVAL` and `YVAL` with the actual points on your plot.

```
var placeholder = $("#" + divId);

var o = plot.pointOffset({ x: XVAL, y: YVAL});

placeholder.append("<div style='position:absolute;left:" + (o.left) + "px;top:" + o.top + "px;color:#666;font-size:smaller'>VALUE</div>");
```

Comment: I don't have XVAL beacuse i am drawing horizontal line

Comment: @user3189828 Right, XVAL would just give a guideline of where along the horizontal line you want the label to be.